# Find all users with specific role using rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, rubygems, roles

How can i get all users with specific role when using rolify? I've tried the following but it didn't help:

```
User.with_role :admin
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `with_role' for #<Class:0x0000000743f9c0>
```

Couldn't find any way to do this.

Comment: Are you able to perform other operations using rolify.

Comment: @GhostRider
Other operations such ad adding a role to a user works properly.

Comment: just check my ans below.. it should fix the issue

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the with_role method with a User class to find all users who has a role in version 3.1.0.

```
User.with_role :admin
```

Comment: with "where"

@courriers = User.where.not(latitude: nil, longitude:nil ).with_role :Courrier

Answer (score 9):

I'd ask the role for it's users

```
admins = Role.find_by_name('admin').users
```

the with_role method is for a particular user instance, not at the class-level for all users. If you want to implement that you'd have to do something like this:

```
#not 100% on this code, haven't tested it, but you get the idea.
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.with_role(role)
     my_role = Role.find_by_name(role)
     where(:role => my_role)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you mentioned resourcify in the models in order to put roles on

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify
end
```

With this you can use with_role and find_roles class methods.

Comment: Trying to do it like this gives the following:
`User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."resource_type" = 'User' WHERE (roles.name = 'user' AND roles.resource_type = 'User')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x36e47c4>`

Comment: This was an issue which has been fixed, just check this https://github.com/EppO/rolify/commit/da1ec59acda83b9114aeb410c99b1ce6e0866648

Comment: Using resourcify in user model breaks succh methods as `all`, `first` etc. When i call User.all i get `NoMethodError: undefined method `find_or_create_by' for #<Rolify::Adapter::ResourceAdapter:0x00000005ed3870>`

Comment: @innocent_rifle try to use rolify for User model and add roles using user instance. check https://github.com/EppO/rolify/issues/69

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use joins, try this:

```
User.with_role(:admin).joins(:other_table).(other_table:{some_field: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need an aditional "where"

```
@courriers = User.where.not(latitude: nil, longitude:nil ).with_role :Courrier
```